# typecasting structs to obtain individual field addresses

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct test{
    char b;
    int a;
    int c ; 
    };
int main()
{
    struct test inst;
    struct test *ptr_test = &inst;
    char * ptr_ch;
    int* ptr_i;

    /*ptr_ch = (char *) ptr_test;*/
    ptr_ch = (char*)ptr_test;
    ptr_i = (int *) ptr_test;
    *ptr_ch = 'b';
    *ptr_i = 13; 

    printf("char b = %c, int a = %d int c = %d", inst.b, inst.a, inst.c);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to give the appropriate values of a,b and garbage value of c.
But on the terminal, if I do ./a.out the output is:

**, int a = 134513785 int c = 13173540**

When I do $./a.out > tmp; vim tmp, the output is:

**char b = ^M, int a = 134513785 int c = 12714788**

What is the problem?

I wanted to access individual fields of the struct using typecasting.

for instance, I wanted to know another way to return the value of &(inst.a).

Answer (score 2):

Your pointers

```
ptr_ch = (char*)ptr_test;
ptr_i = (int *) ptr_test;
```

do not automatically refer to the first apropriate member variable (in your case b and a). Rather they just reinterpret the pointer to the structure as pointer to `char` or `int`, so they point to the same location, the address of your structure. With the `char` you **might** be lucky that it's the first member and you are really pointing to the `char`, but your `int` pointer points to the same address and therefore overwrites it with platform- and compiler-dependent garbage.

So don't do those kinds of things (or do them when you really know what you are doing and, more important, **where** (on what platform and with what compiler) you are doing it).

Answer (score 1):

ptr_ch and ptr_i point to the same memory location:

```
ptr_ch = (char*)ptr_test;
ptr_i = (int *) ptr_test;
```

when you do the following you are reading from the same memory address:

```
*ptr_ch = 'b'; //write the first sizeof(char) byte of the structure ptr_test
*ptr_i = 13;   //write the first sizeof(int) bytes of the structure ptr_test overwriting some bytes wrote before
```

You should eventually do something like:

```
ptr_ch = &(ptr_test->b);
*ptr_ch = 'b';
ptr_i = &(ptr_test->a);
*ptr_i = 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use the typecasting? Why not do the following:

```
ptr_ch = &(ptr_test->b);
ptr_i = &(ptr_test->a);
```

Comment: If you're not explaining what the problem is and therefore answering his question in any way, then it would better fit as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`13` is decimal for an ASCII carriage return - when you do `*ptr_i = 13;`, you're setting `b` to that 13.  If you change your print out to look like:

```
printf("char b = %c (%d), int a = %d int c = %d", inst.b, inst.b, inst.a, inst.c);
```

You'll see that you get:

```
(13), int a = 1 int c = 1606416024
```

as output instead.  The carriage return character is causing your `char b` output to get overwritten by the output following the carriage return character.  It might be more obvious if you used a different number than 13.  For example, using 86, you'll get:

```
char b = V, int a = 1 int c = 1606416024
```

as the output.  The reason `a` and `c` don't make sense is because they're uninitialized.

You can't just typecast a structure pointer to a pointer of another type and expect the compiler to extract a pointer to a field inside that structure for you - that's not how it works.  I think you might have been trying to do this:

```
ptr_ch = &ptr_test->b;
ptr_i = &ptr_test->a;
```

Here's a complete example program that does what I think you're trying for:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test {
  char b;
  int a;
  int c; 
};

int main(void)
{
  struct test inst = {0, 0, 0};
  struct test *ptr_test = &inst;
  char *ptr_ch;
  int *ptr_i;

  ptr_ch = &ptr_test->b;
  ptr_i = &ptr_test->a;
  *ptr_ch = 'b';
  *ptr_i = 86; 

  printf("char b = %c, int a = %d int c = %d\n", inst.b, inst.a, inst.c);

  return 0;
}
```

And its output:

```
char b = b, int a = 86 int c = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the strict conforming offsetof macro, which calculates the offset of any struct element from struct begin:

```
 ptr_ch = (char*)ptr_test;
*ptr_ch = 'b';

 ptr_i = ptr_ch + offsetof(struct test,a);
*ptr_i = 13; 
 ptr_i = ptr_ch + offsetof(struct test,c);
*ptr_i = 14;
```

Comment: The lines that assign to `ptr_i` need casts. C does not permit implicit conversion from `char *` to `int *`.